# storage size of ‘tzp’ isn’t known

Tags: c

So I'm trying to use this piece of code to benchmark:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>

double get_time()
{
    struct timeval t;
    struct timezone tzp;
    gettimeofday(&t, &tzp);
    return t.tv_sec + t.tv_usec*1e-6;
}
```

But for some reason I keep getting this error

```
error: storage size of ‘tzp’ isn’t known
warning: unused variable ‘tzp’
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Works fine here. What's the platform (OS+compiler)?

Comment: Not sure what the compiler is (I'm SSHing into a university system) but the CFLAGS are -W -Wall -ansi -g -O0 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=500 -MM

Answer (score 5):

You defined `_XOPEN_SOURCE=500`. According to the [X/Open 5](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/gettimeofday.html), the second argument is of type `void*` and must be `NULL`:

> ```
> int gettimeofday(struct timeval *tp, void *tzp);
> ```
>
> [..]
>
> If tzp is not a null pointer, the behaviour is unspecified.

If you want the prototype specified in the linux manual, you need to

```
#define __USE_BSD
```

However, if you pass anything other than `NULL`, it will return an error.

Answer (score 1):

You can just get rid of the 'tzp' variable.

From the gettimeofday man page:

> ```
> If either tv or tz is NULL, the corresponding structure is not set or returned.
>
> The use of the timezone structure is obsolete; the tz argument should normally be specified as NULL.
> ```

So your code should be something like:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>

double get_time()
{
    struct timeval t;
    gettimeofday(&t, NULL);
    return t.tv_sec + t.tv_usec*1e-6;
}
```